# How to connect to TFS Project without having access to the TFS Team Project Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have access to a particular TFS Project on my server.  I want to access this project programmatically with the TFS API.  I see no way of accessing the project directly, instead I have to go through the TfsTeamProjectCollection.  However, when I attempt to authenticate to the TfsTeamProjectCollection, I am denied permissions.  When I call the `Authenticate()` method is when I receive this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 
'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException' occurred in 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

Additional information: HTTP code 407: Proxy Authentication Required
```

Here is my code:

```
const string destProjectName = "Test_Dest";
var destUri = new Uri("https://mytfs.server.com:####/tfs/MyProjectCollection");
var destBasicCreds = new BasicAuthCredential(new NetworkCredential("domain\username", "password"));
var destCreds = new TfsClientCredentials(destBasicCreds) { AllowInteractive = false };
var destTpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(destUri, destCreds);
destTpc.Authenticate();
```

I have tried both BasicAuthCredential and WindowsCredential, and get the same error.  Is there something else I should be trying?

Comment: That doesn't strike me as a TFS authentication issue, more of a proxy issue. Are you using a proxy server?

Comment: What kind of client is this code being called from? And from where?

Comment: @ChrisBint, I agree.  After some futher testing, I found that if I actually go to the web page and login there, then my code executes.  Guess I'll have to research authenticating to a proxy.  Any tips?

Comment: @Mike Cheel, I am currently calling this code from the debugger in visual studio.  =)

Comment: I meant from outside of your domain \ network or inside?

Comment: I am accessing a Tfs server that is outside my domain.